# Display data from array to multiple elements in HTML Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to show a list of informations from an XML to a list using Angular 4 and Angular Material.
I have already converted the XML to JSON and the **JSON** I retrieve is like this:

```
{
    "json": {

        "0": [{
                "Name": "John",
                "Address": "5th street",
                "Phone": "555-123-456"
            }

        ],
        "1": [{
                "Name": "Mary",
                "Address": "4th street",
                "Phone": "555-654-321"
            }

        ],
        "2": [{
                "Name": "Harry",
                "Address": "3th street",
                "Phone": "555-124-231"
            }

        ]

    }
}
```

this is my **ts** file: `[i]` is the id and id has dozens of entries.

```
for (let i = 0; i< json.length; i++){
              this.name = json[i]['Name'];
              this.address = json[i]['Address'];
              this.phone = json[i]['Phone'];
 }
```

this is my **html** file:

```
<mat-list>
  <h3 mat-subheader>Your info</h3>
  <mat-list-item>
    <h2 mat-line>Your name is: <b>{{name}}</b></h2>
    <p mat-line> Your address is: <b> {{address}} </b></p>
    <p mat-line> Your phone is: <b> {{phone}} </b></p>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
```

The thing is, the list has dozens of rows but it is showing the first only.
My intention was to have all the items loaded on page.
Already tried using `*ngFor` but it didn't work.

I know I might have missed something stupid but I've tried a lot and searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you are getting confused over iterating in ts file will get reflected in html...the thing is use ngFor over the jsonPosicao...as in ts file your are keep on assigning the values to same variable ..which will finally hold the last item...so it can show only one item

Comment: Please clarify "Already tried using *ngFor but it didn't work."

Comment: I have updated the question with the json I retrieve so you understand why the `[i]['Name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your html

```
<mat-list>
    <h1 mat-subheader>Your info</h1>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let stack of stackdata">
      <h2 mat-line>Your name is: <b>{{stack.Name}}</b></h2>
      <p mat-line> Your address is: <b> {{stack.Address}} </b></p>
      <p mat-line> Your phone is: <b> {{stack.Phone}} </b></p>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
```

> In your ts

```
stackjson : any
stackdata  = []
  ngOnInit() { // or in a method where you are getting the data..
   this.dataService.
   getData().subscribe(res => {
    this.stackjson=res.json().json;
    console.log(this.stackjson);
    for(let index in this.stackjson) 
      {
        //console.log(this.stackjson[index][0]);
        this.stackdata.push(this.stackjson[index][0]); //using this array to display data
      }
   });   
  }
```

> //or use this instead of for loop
>   this.stackdata = Object.keys(this.stackjson).map((k) => this.stackjson[k][0])

And the json is the data that you had given

Here is the result : 
[image]

Adding plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/8lINUBWerEnVtF9BWIAj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you post the full code you used in plunker or jsfiddle? What is dataService in this context? Thanks!

Comment: I saved your json content under assets folder , i used dataService to fetch data from assets/stack.json . will put in plunker/fiddle and let you know by 11:00pm IST once after going to room .Thanks

Comment: Let me know what error you are facing when following the above method

Comment: Added plunker url !!! Assigned your json input to input varaible and storing the input.json to stackjson[in plunker] instead of using dataService[which i used in my host]

Comment: Highly appreciated!!! Any idea of how I display childs? For example if the Phone has a child that starts with another 0 and then Phone1, Phone2 and Phone3. Can't display them doing ``{{stack.Phone.0.Phone1}}``. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: is this what you are asking for Phone :{ "0": 
[ { "Phone1": "123",
   "Phone2": "456",
   "Phone3": "789"
  }
]
}

Comment: if above is the case i.e, stack.Phone equals to this value { "0": [ { "Phone1": "123", "Phone2": "456", "Phone3": "789" } ] } then you can access  stack.Phone[0][0].PhoneX where X=1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

```
 <mat-list-item *ngFor="let posicao of jsonPosicao ">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>directions_car</mat-icon>
    <h2 mat-line>Your name is: <b>{{posicao.name}}</b></h2>
    <p mat-line> Your address is: <b> {{posicao.address}} </b></p>
    <p mat-line> Your phone is: <b> {{posicao.phone}} </b></p>
 </mat-list-item>
```

I'm confused by your quest and your desired results but from what you are trying to do in the javascript seems like you could use the ngFor like this.

```
{ 
   "json": [
            {
                    "Id":"1",
                    "Name": "John",
                    "Address": "5th street",
                    "Phone": "555-123-456"
                }
            ,
            {
                    "Id":"2",
                    "Name": "Mary",
                    "Address": "4th street",
                    "Phone": "555-654-321"
                }
            ,
            {
                    "Id":"3",
                    "Name": "Harry",
                    "Address": "3th street",
                    "Phone": "555-124-231"
                }     
        ]
    }
```

If you want to keep the data structure of the JSON, change html to this

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let posicao of jsonPosicao ">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>directions_car</mat-icon>
    <h2 mat-line>Your name is: <b>{{posicao[0].name}}</b></h2>
    <p mat-line> Your address is: <b> {{posicao[0].address}} </b></p>
    <p mat-line> Your phone is: <b> {{posicao[0].phone}} </b></p>
</mat-list-item>
```

Comment: That didn't work, but thanks for the try. I have updated the question with the json I retrieve so you understand why the `[i]['Name']`

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the structure of your JSON before retrieving the data?

Comment: Hey @NicoLA I can't modify the JSON structure as I'm converting it from XML. Tried your code for the kept data structure but didn't work. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you are not using the iterated object properties. You need to used *ngFor and assign that single iterated object to you list-item elements. As per your code snippet, you can simply paste given code:

```
<mat-list>
  <h3 mat-subheader>Ypur info</h3>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of jsonPosicao">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>directions_car</mat-icon>
    <h2 mat-line>Your name is: <b>item.Name</b></h2>
    <p mat-line> Your address is: <b>item.Address</b></p>
    <p mat-line> Your phone is: <b>item.Phone</b></p>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
```

Main thing is you use your iterated object viz. item in this case.

Comment: Not that, but thanks for the try. I have updated the question with the json I retrieve so you understand why the `[i]['Name']`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the model json with properties Id, Name, Address, Phone.
Than create `jsonList: json[] = []` specifying that list will be of type json object in your ts file and add your data into list.

Than in your html

```
<mat-list>
  <h3 mat-subheader>Your info</h3>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let info of jsonList">
    <h2 mat-line>Your name is: <b>{{info.Name}}</b></h2>
    <p mat-line> Your address is: <b> {{info.Address}} </b></p>
    <p mat-line> Your phone is: <b> {{info.Phone}} </b></p>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
```

It now will show all of your data.